# Best HTTP Request analyzer

Tags: http, http-headers, web-testing

I want to analyze the HTTP Requests generated when I am interacting with a web application through my browser.

Can anyone suggest a tool that I can use to see the outgoing Http Requests from my browser?

I want to see the entire Http Request, not only the header.

Comment: You didn't specify which OS you're using?

Comment: Microsoft Windows Operating System.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) which is freeware works with all browsers, but there are several others, including the built-in dev tools for the browser of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Burp Suite community edition, with that we can do things like view requests response and some other stuff, it commonly used by bug hunters. If you are good at any programming, you can built your own tools for this purpose, there are a lot of libraries out there. PS your programming skill will increase.